# Is the duplicated span tag causing my output to be returned as none?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

i am trying to get contact information from a company listing website wuth web scraping using beautiful soup.
 The contact information is stored in a span tag with a id='valuephone_'or 'valuewebsite_'

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings"
html=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')

for i in soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-9 col-xs-8 company-details'):
    website = soup.find('span',{'id':'valuewebsite'+str(i)})
    contact = soup.find('span',{'id':'valuephone'+str(i)})
    print(website,contact)
```

```py
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
None None
```

Does it have to do with the two span tags, because the webpage has a event function where by the number is shown when clicked on.
Images:[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rG2.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WBj7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You don't get the ID, because you miss `_` in the `id`.

You can use `zip()` and CSS selectors to obtain the info, for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.timesbusinessdirectory.com/company-listings'


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for i, (web, phone) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('[id^="valuewebsite_"]'),
                                     soup.select('[id^="valuephone_"]')), 1):
    print(i, web.get_text(strip=True), phone.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
1 www.m3bp.com (65) 6896 5585
2 www.citisafe.com.sg (65) 6482 4582
3 www.excelsisconceptz.com.sg (65) 6684 9454
4 www.cheecheeandco.com (65) 6298 0456
5 www.chengmeng.com (65) 6745 9900
6 www.hiapseng.com (65) 6897 8082,(65) 6861 0667
7 schempp-ps.com.sg (65) 6742 5467
8 www.tccorporatenet.com (65) 6463 2139
9 www.witco.com.sg (65) 6482 0371
10 www.anaservices.com.sg (65) 6369 9638
```

EDIT (answers to questions in comments):

1.) What is `^` for in `select('[id^="valuewebsite_"]')` ?

the `select()` method uses [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) - `^` means to select every tag whose `id` attribute value begins with `"valuewebsite_"`

2.) What is the point of ziping?

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function "zips" together two iterables: In this case for every website there's one phone.

3.) And what is 1 for at the end of the for loop?

`1` belongs to [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#enumerate), it's the `start=` parameter. It means that the `i` variable in for-loop begins from `1`.

Comment: thanks alot but i would like to clarify 3 things  1)what is ^  for in  select('[id^="valuewebsite_"]')   2) what is the point of ziping  3)and what is 1 for at the end of the for loop

Comment: @Chowjinglun See my answer.